# How to encrypt the .viminfo file and still get Vim to read it?

Tags: viminfo, encryption

I love using Vim yet have a lot of very sensitive, encrypted files to edit, sometimes on an unencrypted drive, and can't have any residual information from these files forensically accessible to other users of that hardware or others. I realize I can just do `:set viminfo=` but this disables lots of the best features. How can I get Vim to encrypt the `.viminfo` file instead so that no information is stored on the drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean swap files?

.viminfo is stored in your home directory, even when you're editing files on external disks.

Swap files default to being stored in the same directory as the file you're editing though.

You can use settings `viminfofile` and `directory` to set where the .viminfo and swap files (respectively) are stored, so that they are stored within an encrypted drive/partition.

I use this:

```
set directory=$HOME/tmp/vim/swap//
```

because it speeds up working on slow remote-mounted disks such as sshfs.

You could do that plus something like (untested)...

```
set viminfofile=$home/tmp/vim/info
```